# declare variable in loop but without initialization in c

Tags: c, gcc

I'm practicing C programming skills, finding some tricks that already exist, and figuring it out.
One of my practicing items is that declare a variable in the loop but without initialization. I have code like the following.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        int a;
        int b = 0;
        printf("i=%d, a=%d, b=%d\n", i, a++, b++);
    }
}
```

after compiled with

> gcc test.c //The ver of GCC is 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)

the binary output is:

```
i=1, a=0, b=0
i=2, a=1, b=0
i=3, a=2, b=0
i=4, a=3, b=0
i=5, a=4, b=0
i=6, a=5, b=0
i=7, a=6, b=0
i=8, a=7, b=0
i=9, a=8, b=0
i=10, a=9, b=0
```

The output was as expected because `a` was not given an explicit value, which means that the program will reuse the previous value in each loop. Semantically, we want to use a fresh new `a`, but logic under the hood has been modified. So I blame it on the GCC optimization level and try to prove it

However, I changed the GCC optimization level from O0-O3, even Og(when set with Og, the value of `a` begins with random), the result didn't change at all.

I know that if an exact value is given to `a`, the program runs as expected.

Is there no way out? if so, it's really confusing.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  then use the  [GDB debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Comment: `Is there no way out? if so, it's really confusing`. I am also confused. "Way out" from? I think this is XY question. Are you trying to get a random number? `One of my practicing items is that declare a variable in the loop but without initialization` is confusing me more - practicing on invalid buggy code will just make you a bad programmer. Instead I would suggest stick to writing proper code with predictable defined behavior. `Semantically, we want to use a fresh new a` "Use" where and how? What does it mean "fresh"?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity, what I mean is，making the output of A and B consistent without modifying the code

Comment: "Consistent"? With what? According to what rules? How to measure "consistency"? The output is consistent with the C language - the value is uninitialized, it may have __any__ value and it has __any__ value.

Comment: I've already known that it's an invalid buggy code. maybe some words I described were out of place a little bit, but it won't get out of my road on figuring all of these pitfalls out. All you did is what is, but nothing about why is. Just Stop finger-pointing, tell me what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The output was as expected because `a` was not given an explicit value, which means that the program will reuse the previous value in each loop.

It does not mean that, and there is no expected output.

Per the C standard, the value of an uninitialized object is *indeterminate*<sup>1</sup>, which means not only is its value not specified but that the program may behave as if it does not hold any fixed value.<sup>2</sup> If it were used multiple times during its lifetime, the program could act like it had a different value each time. For example, the C standard would allow `printf("%d %d %d\n", a, a, a);` to print “34 -10200773 2147483204”. The value of `a` could also be a trap value, if its type has such values in the particular C implementation.

In addition, using the value of an uninitialized object with automatic storage duration that has not had its address taken is explicitly undefined behavior.<sup>3</sup>

That you got the output you did is merely happenstance of how the compiler works. It is not designed behavior and could vary from compiler version to compiler version and depending on circumstances. A compiler could just as easily have removed the `++` during optimization because it is the last operation on `a` during its lifetime (which ends when execution of the block it is defined in ends), meaning the value is not used afterward, so there is no defined effect for the increment. Then you might have seen no change in the output from iteration to iteration.

Another possibility is the value might not have started at zero.

Another possibility is the compiler might have used some processor register for `a` instead of memory, and, since `a` is uninitialized, the output of second and subsequent iterations would be whatever `printf` happened to leave in that register.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> C 2018 6.2.4 6, about objects with automatic storage duration without variable length array type: “The initial value of the object is indeterminate.”

<sup>2</sup> C 2018 3.19.2, “indeterminate value”: “either an unspecified value or a trap representation”. 3.19.3, “unspecified value”: “valid value of the relevant type where this document imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance”.

<sup>3</sup> C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, about converting an lvalue to a value: “If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.”

Answer (score 1):

> my practicing items is that declare a variable in the loop but without initialization

It's a bad practice to use un-initialized variables in expressions, we cannot predict the outcome, don't depend on it even if we get same output every time you run.

> The output was as expected because a was not given an explicit value, which means that the program will reuse the previous value in each loop.

**No**

That is just an Undefined Behavior, your program is behaving as if we declared

`int a;`
as
`static int a;`

But, I am not really sure it behaves same way if the program size increases or placement of `int a` changes.(like you declare `a` out side loop)

And you seem to know how to use it correctly(initialize before use), so use it that way.